# How to stop TeamCity from rebuilding docker dependencies every time?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, teamcity, bitbucket

I have a TeamCity build project that parameterizes a docker-compose.yml template with the build versions of a dozen Docker containers, so in order to get the build_counter from each container, I have them set as snapshot dependencies in the docker-compose build job. Each container's Dockerfile and other files are in their own BitBucket repo, and they have triggers for the appropriate files. In the snapshot dependencies in the docker-compose build I have them set to "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" but it still tries to run all of the dependent builds even though there aren't any changes in their respective repos.

This makes what should be a very simple and quick build in to a very long build. And often times, one of the dependent builds will fail with "could not collect changes: connection refused" and I suspect it has to do with TC trying to hit all of these different repos all at once.

Is there something I can do to not trigger a build of every dependency every time the docker-compose build is run?

Edit:

Here's an example of what our docker-compose.yml.j2 looks like: http://termbin.com/b2xy

Obviously, I've sanitized it for sharing, and our real docker-compose template has about a dozen services listed.

Here is an example Dockerfile for one of the services: http://termbin.com/upins

Comment: When the repos are all being built, does TC show pending changes in any of the repositories?

Comment: No, they all show "no changes".

Comment: Can you share a dockerfile? There are commands which invalidate the build cache and cause all following commands to run again instead of hitting cache.

Comment: I edited the question to include examples.

Comment: Possibly helpful, likely you've RTFM already. [Snapshot Dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Snapshot+Dependencies). Something in here explains why the compose build config isn't counting any of the Dockerfile build configs as "suitable"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the source code of your build (parameterized docker-compose.yml) and brute-force your build every time, you could consider building the containers independently while tagging them with a version increment, and labels. After the build store the images in a local registry. Use docker-compose to suit your runtime needs. docker-compose can use multiple yaml files, so if you need other images for a particular build, just pull the other images you need. For production use another yaml file that composes the system to run. Add LABEL to your Dockerfile. See http://label-schema.org//rc1/ for a set of labels that suit your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your proposing. Currently the containers are being built in separate TC projects, but docker-compose build project needs to know the build_counter of each container's last successful build, so we have them set as snapshot dependencies. Are you suggesting instead to have each container build job generate their own docker-compose snippet and then use the "-f" option to docker-compose to merge each of them at run-time? Also, I edited the question to provide some examples of what we're doing.

Comment: Your stack was unclear at first. I advise not using snapshots because these can change any time and hence cause a build each time (especially with package.json dependencies), build your images and tag these so you can depend on version from the registry instead of other builds. In other words de-couple.

Comment: TC has separate threads watching repo’s and will trigger all builds involved. TC does not watch Nexus to my knowledge.

Comment: Ok, but if I remove the snapshot dependencies, I can't access the build counter variables (i.e, %dep.MyProject_AServiceBuild.build.counter%) from the docker builds in my docker-compose build. Is there another way to reference those variables?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the use of LABEL in Dockerfile

Comment: I'm still not sure how that answers my question. How would I get the version number from the other Teamcity builds in to my docker-compose template?

Comment: The build counter variables should be irrelevant. You pull images from the registry using tags just as you would with third-party images (but yes, you can use a build counter to tag an image) In docker-compose-dev.yml  you use the tag ‘latest’, you run tests and curl DELETE from your registry if the image is bad.

Comment: Right, but we want a "prod" compose file that still has specific versions of the containers, not just always the latest.

Comment: I would go for the vector of images and versions that withstood all integration tests. This is emergent information, unknown at build-time of the individual images. Therefore the docker-compose.yml for “prod” could be the “artefact” of your integration tests.

Comment: Right, but how do I know the versions of the images when building the prod compose file without linking the docker-compose build job to the docker image build jobs as snapshot dependencies?

Comment: Teamcity needs to log some meta data on the versions of working images after tests pass, you write a script to combine the meta data into your compose file. The working combination should be determined by tests, so your test job generates the yaml, not the build jobs.

Comment: Where would this script to combine the meta data live if not in a separate build job that has the other build jobs as dependencies?

Comment: Because that's basically what we're doing, so I'm still not seeing how your recommendation is different from what we're doing and how it can get that metadata without having the other builds as dependencies.

Comment: Maybe ‘staging’ is the concept that needs to dawn on you?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but I have come across this issue and you can't do what sounds reasonable i.e. get recent green builds without rebuilding. This is partly because of what the snapshot dependencies are designed to do by Jetbrains.

The basic idea is that dependencies are for synchronized revisions of code: that is if you build Compose at a certain time, it will need to use not just its own versions of source code at that point in time but also the code for all the dependencies that also comes from that point of time, regardless of whether anything significant has changed.

In my example, there were always changes because the same repo was used for lots of projects and had unrelated changes that would not trigger a build but would make the project appear behind and cause a build.

If your dependencies have NOT changed and show no changes pending, then they shouldn't build. In this case, you need to tick "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one". "Enforce Revisions Synchronization" is slightly confusing. If ticked, it will find older builds that match the first build after your build was triggered. If unticked, it can use newer builds.